# Class Digit in C++

Tags: c++, class, integer

Question:

> Please create a class Digit represent a single digit in base ten.
>
> Class Digit should contain two constructor, one with no parameter and
> set digit to 0, another one with one integer parameter and use the
> parameter to set the digit.
>
> Create two function member setDigit and getDigit to set and get the
> digit int integer type. You should set digit to 0 if setDigit receive
> a unreasonable parameter.

I don't know how wrong to my code.
The online Judge displayed wrong answer.
Please give me some idea.
Thanks.

```
#include <limits.h>
class Digit
{
  public:
  int digit;
  Digit()
  {
    digit = 0;
  }
  Digit(int n)
  {
    digit = n;
  }
  void setDigit(int n)
  {
    if (n < INT_MIN || n > INT_MAX)
      digit = 0;
    else
      digit = n;
  }
  int getDigit() const
  {
    return digit;
  }
};
```

Comment: Digits and numbers are not the same thing. The digits in base ten are 0, 1 ,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9.

Comment: Hint:  is `13` a reasonable digit?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but there cannot be an `int` value which is less than INT_MIN, and there cannot be an `int` value that is greater than `INT_MAX`. That's the point of having those constants. If `setDigit` took an argument of type `long` that test might be meaningful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use 0 and 9 inclusive instead of INT_MIN (-INT_MAX - 1) and INT_MAX (2^31 - = 2147483647 on my box).  You could use a uint8_t instead of int if you wanted.  Also use the same logic in the constructors, i.e. by calling setDigit() from them:

```
Digit() {
    setDigit(0);
}

Digit(int n) {
    setDigit(n);
}

void setDigit(int n) {
    digit = (n >= 0 && n <= 9) ? n : 0;
}
```

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Of course.  Brain fart on my part.  Updated answer.